# How to add a click listener to an A element

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to run the following when I press on the a-tag:

```html
<a id="demo">Hello.</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
  var url = "http://www.google.com";
  var myWindow = window.open(url, "http://www.google.com", "width=700,height=275");
</script>
```

How do I make it happen correctly, only running the var when I press the a-tag? I based it on the following:

```html
<a id="demo">Hello.</a>
    
<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
  function myFunction() {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi there!";}
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to put both var statements into myFunction()

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include those two `var` statements inside your `onclick` function, so they run all the time.

Additionally, for your `<a>` element to be correct, it needs an `href` attribute. If you really don't want to navigate anywhere, you don't really need an `<a>` element at all, you can use almost any other element and just assign it a `click` event handler exactly the same way you are doing with the `<a>` element.  See code below for an example:

```css
#demo { cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hello.</d>

<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
    var url = "http://www.google.com";
    var myWindow = window.open(url, "http://www.google.com", "width=700,height=275");   
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just lost the definition of `myFunction` which is called in the click handler.

You can move it directly inside the onclick, like so:

```html
<a id="demo">Hello.</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
      var url = "http://www.google.com";
      var myWindow = window.open(url, "http://www.google.com", "width=700,height=275");
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code like this:

```
<a id="demo">Hello.</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Hi")
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    

    <a id="demo">Hello.</a>

    <script>
       document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
       window.location.href="https://www.google.com"
       };
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers.  Include some explanation of what you have changed, why it works, etc.